# Get the biggest price using MAX() function

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using SQL Oracle, and I want to change my query using `MAX` function and not `ROWNUM`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT a.name, price.price
FROM price
LEFT JOIN a 
ON a.id = price.tk_a
ORDER BY price.price DESC)
WHERE ROWNUM <=1;
```

Any help or suggestions please?

Comment: What tables and colums do you have, and what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Table a, with names of courses and table price with prices. They are connected via foreign key and ID. 
I want to get maximum price and course name, but not using DESC and ROWNUM but MAX(price).

Comment: Why do you want to use MAX instead of ROWNUM? If there are multiple rows with the same price you can use a Windowed Aggregate Function, e.g. RANK

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `MAX` aggregate function with `KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY ... )` to get the maximum of another column:

```
SELECT MAX( a.name ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY p.price DESC ) AS name,
       MAX( p.price ) AS price
FROM   a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN price p
       ON ( a.id = p.tk_a );
```

Answer (score 1):

MAX and group by

```
SELECT a.name, MAX(p.price)
FROM price
LEFT JOIN a ON a.id = p.tk_a
GROUP BY a.name
ORDER BY p.price DESC
```

If you just want the single MAX price then use this

```
SELECT MAX(p.price), (SELECT MAX(b.name) FROM a b LEFT JOIN price pp ON b.id = pp.tk_a WHERE a.id = b.id AND p.price = pp.price) AS name
FROM price
LEFT JOIN a ON a.id = p.tk_a
ORDER BY p.price DESC
```

Comment: Thats what I tried, but I get all of 10 columns and not only the MAX one.

Comment: Updated answer, use second query to get single max price

Comment: In that way I get only price and not the name of the course too.

Comment: @HC1122 should get you what you want now

Comment: What does that "b" stands for?

Comment: @HC1122 its just an aliased table name so you can join it to the main query

Comment: SQL Error: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select a1.name, p1.price
from price p1
JOIN a a1 ON a1.id = p1.tk_a
JOIN (SELECT MAX(p.price)
      FROM price p) C on p1.price = c.price
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT a.name,MAX( price.price)
FROM price
LEFT JOIN a 
ON a.id = price.tk_a
GROUP BY a.name 
ORDER BY price.price DESC)
```

Comment: I don't want to use ROWNUM only MAX function.

Comment: @HC1122 removed Rownum check it

Comment: I don't know why I get all of 10 rows selected and not only the maximum one.

Comment: @HC1122 can you plz provide sample data